# Is AGP 3.5 compatible with Gradle 6?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

I would like to know whether I can start using Gradle 6 with Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) 3.5.

According to the official documentation they are not compatible:

> Plugin version | Required Gradle version
>
> 3.5.0+    | 5.4.1-5.6.4
>
> Source:
>   https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

**However**, further down the page (for AGP 3.5.0) you can read:

> This version of the Android plugin requires the following:
>
> Gradle 5.4.1 or higher.

Probably the last part is just old information (published before Gradle 6 was released?).

But if so, what is known to be broken regarding Gradle 6?

Answer (score 0):

I am on AS 3.5.2 and AGP 3.5.2, I simply swapped `distributionUrl` in `gradle-wrapper.properties` to

```
https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.0.1-all.zip
```

Synced, builded and deployed to emulator, everything worked fine.

> Should we probably do it? No

Because there are a lot of external plugins, task and infinite things that can go wrong using a not officially supported plugin for that specific version.

I don't think risking to break something (that you even can't notice) is worth the upgrade, but this is a personal choice :)

Comment: Not really the answer I was looking for. I know that it compiles and all. It even _seems_ to work (at least for library projects). By the way, you should use the build wrapper script to update Gradlew and not edit manually, otherwise some files may not be up-to-date.

Comment: I don't think someone can come here and say "Go on with gradle 6, it works 100% with everything" if is not someone which works in the AGP team

Comment: True. But I'm also interested in any known issues now that the compatibility status is somewhat vague.

Comment: Don't think there are "known" issue, because nobody uses it by default. You probably are a bit "alone" in this process. You can go on and see how it goes, if you don't find problems impacting your specific gradle configuration you are ok. If your question is because you want to implement custom tasks heavy relying on Gradle 6 features, probably I would not going forward with this. Moreover having the table with 3.5.0+ | 5.4.1-5.6.4 is not "vague" enough to me (at least).

Comment: Sure. But at the same time you have the official information saying "This version of the Android plugin requires the following:

Gradle 5.4.1 or higher." Could it be that the Android team simply does not know whether it works? That they just noticed that Gradle 6 was released and in panic updated the documentation?

Comment: I've found this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144896521 which is linked in the release of [AS 3.6 RC1](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/12/android-studio-36-release-candidate-1.html) which states that AGP 3.6 is builded against Gradle 5.6.4. This means that AGP 3.5 is not builded/tested with Gradle 6 for sure. (even if it could work perfectly fine as said)